# How to print x with its value - if it is in y variable

Tags: python, printing

I have a problem with this and I have searched for it but none was the solution for my problem

What I need is to print :

---

```
Variable = '''Daily report

User = Johnny 

Password = 12345

User = Mark

Password = 123456

User = Jeff

Password = 1234567

'''

for "User" in Variable:

   #Print its name/value

   

for "password" in variable:

   #Print its value 

   #(Which starts after the'=')
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the lines of the string. Check if the assignment is to the variable you want to print, then print the corresponding value.

```
for line in Variable.splitlines():
    if ' = ' in line:
        variable, value = line.split(' = ')
        if variable == 'User':
            print(value)
```

Comment: That was helpful more than i thought, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` can easily solve your problem.

```py
import re 

Variable = '''Daily report

User = Johnny 

Password = 12345

User = Mark

Password = 123456

User = Jeff

Password = 1234567

'''

user_password_values = re.findall(r"User = (\w+)\s+\nPassword = (\w+)", variable)
for name, password in user_password_values:
    print(f"name: {name}, Password: {password}")
```